# How can apps use the Google Offline Maps from Android 4+?

Tags: android, google-maps

Android has with version (4+ ?) introduced offline maps where I can on the handset select an area to cache and then Google Maps downloads that map data on the handset.

As I got a comment: I want to use the data, that is already on my device (if the user has done the downloading for offline maps use before). And not open a new data connection to Google's servers (e.g. because data charges would apply).

Can I use that map data from within my app - e.g. by sending the maps app an intent do show an area (perhaps with overlays)?
Or use even the map widget inside my app?

I am not talking about downloading some tiles from the Google servers into my app

Comment: you say you are not talking about downloading some tiles from the Google servers into your app, but that is exactly what you say "offline maps" is doing. Anyway, is this a legal question? Are you asking if it is OK to steal from the thief? ;-)

Comment: Showing through intent might be possible but you cannot use that data within your app.

Comment: +Marcelo: I say I want to use the tiles that the Google Maps app has already downloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I use that map data from within my app - e.g. by sending the maps app an intent do show an area (perhaps with overlays)?

Well, you can invoke a map application using `ACTION_VIEW` and a `geo:` `Intent`. Whether that will view some cached area depends on what map app the user uses and whether or not the user cached the area around your specified latitude and longitude.

> Or use even the map widget inside my app?

While you can integrate a `MapView` in your app, it will not use this cached data. Partially, that is because the `MapView` code predates any of this caching stuff. Partially, that is because the cached data is owned by another process (the Maps app) and therefore is inaccessible to you.

Comment: I don't see that the geo: intent supports any markers or overlays. Otherwise triggering the maps app seems to work and of course the user would have to downloaded the data first :)

Comment: @HeikoRupp: "I don't see that the geo: intent supports any markers or overlays" -- correct. If you want to draw on the map, you need `MapView`, in which case you lose the offline caching. Or, switch to some other mapping solution that offers its own caching (e.g., OpenStreetMap and OSMDroid).

Comment: I know about OSM, but effectively this means additional steps for the user. Looks like I/we "just" need to wait for Google to get that fixed.

Comment: @HeikoRupp: Bear in mind that it may never be "fixed". Even if they update the add-on (which they indicated was a work in progress at the 2012 Google I|O conference), they may not have the rights to allow arbitrary third-party developers to cache that data. Bear in mind that Google licenses some of the map data, so things *Google* is licensed to do is not necessarily something that *we're* licensed to do. "I know about OSM, but effectively this means additional steps for the user" -- like what? OSMDroid bakes the maps into your app, if I understand correctly.