# Can I Access Maps Saved for Offline use by Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, offline

http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57462845-285/save-maps-for-offline-use-in-google-maps-for-android/

Ok so on android the new google maps can allow the user to save the map for offline use.
My question is my app uses google maps, can I access these saved maps from my app when I am in offline mode??

Thanks

Comment: Ahh seems unlikely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130517/how-can-apps-use-the-google-offline-maps-from-android-4

Comment: The maps app and the maps API are very different things.  The Maps API terms of service forbids off line usage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ok so on android the new google maps can allow the user to save the map for offline use.

The Google Maps *application* for Android offers offline caching.

> My question is my app uses google maps, can I access these saved maps from my app when I am in offline mode?

The Google Maps SDK add-on for Android does not offer offline caching, at least not at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not shure, but in my understanding, One uses the GoogleMaps through the Android-Maps-Api. So if you are showing a region you have stored before, the maps-api should deliver stored Map-tiles instead of downloading them from the internet. You can test this, if you store a region around your place, disable all Internet-acces on your phone, and test inside you app, if the stored regions are shown.

EDIT:

Sorry I testet it myself without Result. It will be too nice and easy if that would have worked, maybe Google adds this feature to their API one day

Comment: Just tried doesn't work well in standard usage. Im thinking is there someway to point the MapView towards the internal cache rather than scanning online.

Comment: I thought that, too. It will be the best way to handle this, because a dev can never know which tiles the user has Downloaded. So far, there is no method to get this via the API. It should be possible to get them via a MapsIntent, but on the other side you have no chance to add Custom Overlays. If that is not needed you can go that way.

Comment: Good shout ill have a look at MapsIntents on monday. Although the app does use overlays all the time.... Its silly seems like I can either show overlays with no map or a map with no overlays in offline mode.... ! Its shameful to say that Apple Maps in iOs 6 is much better for this. the MapKit caches map tiles into the system files meaning that any app that uses MapKit can use the centralised cached tiles! How good is that!